# How can I customize the TFS 2012 web access welcome page?

Tags: tfs

The tfs 2012 web access welcome page page includes a link to the administration web site. The link title is "Administer Team Foundation Server" and the url is `http://<server>:8080/tfs/_admin`.

I would like to remove this link from the welcome page as I do not want tfs users poking around the admin site. While the user's can't actually edit anything, they can see some security settings which I would like to remain hidden.

Is it possible to customize the welcome page (ie, remove the admin link), and if so how?

Comment: What are the security settings that you want to hide from the user?

Comment: Really any and all but I don't think they should have access to the admin site at all. When I sign in as one of theses users I can still see project security settings and the team security settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, without editing the html pages directly. You can find them on your TFS server, application tier, if you want to go this route.

But, why do you want to do this in the first place? What are your developers going to do?

Comment: I have external non-developer resources accessing parts of TFS. I'm not to concerned that anyone would do anything malicious, it just seems odd that the users can get into the administrative system.

Comment: Have you tried making the external user to only have limited web access? I believe this hides the admin section icon.  For a user to have anything above limited access they must have a TFS CAL, so you be required by your licensing to look into this option anyway.

Comment: Limited web access is too limiting for my needs.